# How to Implement HTTP byte-range requests in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, video-streaming

I have the problem with video rewind on my site.

I figure out that problem with http headers.

My current controller method which returns video:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/testVideo")
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource testVideo(Principal principal) throws IOException {
   return new FileSystemResource(new File("D:\\oceans.mp4"));
}
```

How to rewrite following code with byte-range supporting?

### P.S.

I have seen following example [http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20100818085302/http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html)

But this code looks hard for me and I cannot understand it. I hope that in spring mvc exists way simpler.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The request for support for http byte-range was open at the time of this answer but is fixed in Spring 4.2.RC1. Check jira [SPR-10805](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10805) or, the PR [here](https://gist.github.com/davinkevin/b97e39d7ce89198774b4).

But based on the code that you linked in your question, Davin Kevin built a [solution](https://gist.github.com/davinkevin/b97e39d7ce89198774b4) that could work for your request.

Code for MultipartFileSender:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by kevin on 10/02/15.
 * See full code here : https://github.com/davinkevin/Podcast-Server/blob/d927d9b8cb9ea1268af74316cd20b7192ca92da7/src/main/java/lan/dk/podcastserver/utils/multipart/MultipartFileSender.java
 */
public class MultipartFileSender {

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 20480; // ..bytes = 20KB.
    private static final long DEFAULT_EXPIRE_TIME = 604800000L; // ..ms = 1 week.
    private static final String MULTIPART_BOUNDARY = "MULTIPART_BYTERANGES";

    Path filepath;
    HttpServletRequest request;
    HttpServletResponse response;

    public MultipartFileSender() {
    }

    public static MultipartFileSender fromPath(Path path) {
        return new MultipartFileSender().setFilepath(path);
    }

    public static MultipartFileSender fromFile(File file) {
        return new MultipartFileSender().setFilepath(file.toPath());
    }

    public static MultipartFileSender fromURIString(String uri) {
        return new MultipartFileSender().setFilepath(Paths.get(uri));
    }

    //** internal setter **//
    private MultipartFileSender setFilepath(Path filepath) {
        this.filepath = filepath;
        return this;
    }

    public MultipartFileSender with(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        request = httpRequest;
        return this;
    }

    public MultipartFileSender with(HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
        response = httpResponse;
        return this;
    }

    public void serveResource() throws Exception {
        if (response == null || request == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (!Files.exists(filepath)) {
            logger.error("File doesn't exist at URI : {}", filepath.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return;
        }

        Long length = Files.size(filepath);
        String fileName = filepath.getFileName().toString();
        FileTime lastModifiedObj = Files.getLastModifiedTime(filepath);

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(fileName) || lastModifiedObj == null) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            return;
        }
        long lastModified = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(lastModifiedObj.toInstant(), ZoneId.of(ZoneOffset.systemDefault().getId())).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        String contentType = "video/mp4";

        // Validate request headers for caching ---------------------------------------------------

        // If-None-Match header should contain "*" or ETag. If so, then return 304.
        String ifNoneMatch = request.getHeader("If-None-Match");
        if (ifNoneMatch != null && HttpUtils.matches(ifNoneMatch, fileName)) {
            response.setHeader("ETag", fileName); // Required in 304.
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_MODIFIED);
            return;
        }

        // If-Modified-Since header should be greater than LastModified. If so, then return 304.
        // This header is ignored if any If-None-Match header is specified.
        long ifModifiedSince = request.getDateHeader("If-Modified-Since");
        if (ifNoneMatch == null && ifModifiedSince != -1 && ifModifiedSince + 1000 > lastModified) {
            response.setHeader("ETag", fileName); // Required in 304.
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_MODIFIED);
            return;
        }

        // Validate request headers for resume ----------------------------------------------------

        // If-Match header should contain "*" or ETag. If not, then return 412.
        String ifMatch = request.getHeader("If-Match");
        if (ifMatch != null && !HttpUtils.matches(ifMatch, fileName)) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_PRECONDITION_FAILED);
            return;
        }

        // If-Unmodified-Since header should be greater than LastModified. If not, then return 412.
        long ifUnmodifiedSince = request.getDateHeader("If-Unmodified-Since");
        if (ifUnmodifiedSince != -1 && ifUnmodifiedSince + 1000 <= lastModified) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_PRECONDITION_FAILED);
            return;
        }

        // Validate and process range -------------------------------------------------------------

        // Prepare some variables. The full Range represents the complete file.
        Range full = new Range(0, length - 1, length);
        List<Range> ranges = new ArrayList<>();

        // Validate and process Range and If-Range headers.
        String range = request.getHeader("Range");
        if (range != null) {

            // Range header should match format "bytes=n-n,n-n,n-n...". If not, then return 416.
            if (!range.matches("^bytes=\\d*-\\d*(,\\d*-\\d*)*$")) {
                response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes */" + length); // Required in 416.
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE);
                return;
            }

            String ifRange = request.getHeader("If-Range");
            if (ifRange != null && !ifRange.equals(fileName)) {
                try {
                    long ifRangeTime = request.getDateHeader("If-Range"); // Throws IAE if invalid.
                    if (ifRangeTime != -1) {
                        ranges.add(full);
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignore) {
                    ranges.add(full);
                }
            }

            // If any valid If-Range header, then process each part of byte range.
            if (ranges.isEmpty()) {
                for (String part : range.substring(6).split(",")) {
                    // Assuming a file with length of 100, the following examples returns bytes at:
                    // 50-80 (50 to 80), 40- (40 to length=100), -20 (length-20=80 to length=100).
                    long start = Range.sublong(part, 0, part.indexOf("-"));
                    long end = Range.sublong(part, part.indexOf("-") + 1, part.length());

                    if (start == -1) {
                        start = length - end;
                        end = length - 1;
                    } else if (end == -1 || end > length - 1) {
                        end = length - 1;
                    }

                    // Check if Range is syntactically valid. If not, then return 416.
                    if (start > end) {
                        response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes */" + length); // Required in 416.
                        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE);
                        return;
                    }

                    // Add range.                    
                    ranges.add(new Range(start, end, length));
                }
            }
        }

        // Prepare and initialize response --------------------------------------------------------

        // Get content type by file name and set content disposition.
        String disposition = "inline";

        // If content type is unknown, then set the default value.
        // For all content types, see: http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp
        // To add new content types, add new mime-mapping entry in web.xml.
        if (contentType == null) {
            contentType = "application/octet-stream";
        } else if (!contentType.startsWith("image")) {
            // Else, expect for images, determine content disposition. If content type is supported by
            // the browser, then set to inline, else attachment which will pop a 'save as' dialogue.
            String accept = request.getHeader("Accept");
            disposition = accept != null && HttpUtils.accepts(accept, contentType) ? "inline" : "attachment";
        }
        logger.debug("Content-Type : {}", contentType);
        // Initialize response.
        response.reset();
        response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", disposition + ";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
        logger.debug("Content-Disposition : {}", disposition);
        response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        response.setHeader("ETag", fileName);
        response.setDateHeader("Last-Modified", lastModified);
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + DEFAULT_EXPIRE_TIME);

        // Send requested file (part(s)) to client ------------------------------------------------

        // Prepare streams.
        try (InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(filepath));
             OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream()) {

            if (ranges.isEmpty() || ranges.get(0) == full) {

                // Return full file.
                logger.info("Return full file");
                response.setContentType(contentType);
                response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + full.start + "-" + full.end + "/" + full.total);
                response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(full.length));
                Range.copy(input, output, length, full.start, full.length);

            } else if (ranges.size() == 1) {

                // Return single part of file.
                Range r = ranges.get(0);
                logger.info("Return 1 part of file : from ({}) to ({})", r.start, r.end);
                response.setContentType(contentType);
                response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + r.start + "-" + r.end + "/" + r.total);
                response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(r.length));
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT); // 206.

                // Copy single part range.
                Range.copy(input, output, length, r.start, r.length);

            } else {

                // Return multiple parts of file.
                response.setContentType("multipart/byteranges; boundary=" + MULTIPART_BOUNDARY);
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT); // 206.

                // Cast back to ServletOutputStream to get the easy println methods.
                ServletOutputStream sos = (ServletOutputStream) output;

                // Copy multi part range.
                for (Range r : ranges) {
                    logger.info("Return multi part of file : from ({}) to ({})", r.start, r.end);
                    // Add multipart boundary and header fields for every range.
                    sos.println();
                    sos.println("--" + MULTIPART_BOUNDARY);
                    sos.println("Content-Type: " + contentType);
                    sos.println("Content-Range: bytes " + r.start + "-" + r.end + "/" + r.total);

                    // Copy single part range of multi part range.
                    Range.copy(input, output, length, r.start, r.length);
                }

                // End with multipart boundary.
                sos.println();
                sos.println("--" + MULTIPART_BOUNDARY + "--");
            }
        }

    }

    private static class Range {
        long start;
        long end;
        long length;
        long total;

        /**
         * Construct a byte range.
         * @param start Start of the byte range.
         * @param end End of the byte range.
         * @param total Total length of the byte source.
         */
        public Range(long start, long end, long total) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
            this.length = end - start + 1;
            this.total = total;
        }

        public static long sublong(String value, int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
            String substring = value.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
            return (substring.length() > 0) ? Long.parseLong(substring) : -1;
        }

        private static void copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output, long inputSize, long start, long length) throws IOException {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int read;

            if (inputSize == length) {
                // Write full range.
                while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    output.flush();
                }
            } else {
                input.skip(start);
                long toRead = length;

                while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    if ((toRead -= read) > 0) {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        output.flush();
                    } else {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, (int) toRead + read);
                        output.flush();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static class HttpUtils {

        /**
         * Returns true if the given accept header accepts the given value.
         * @param acceptHeader The accept header.
         * @param toAccept The value to be accepted.
         * @return True if the given accept header accepts the given value.
         */
        public static boolean accepts(String acceptHeader, String toAccept) {
            String[] acceptValues = acceptHeader.split("\\s*(,|;)\\s*");
            Arrays.sort(acceptValues);

            return Arrays.binarySearch(acceptValues, toAccept) > -1
                    || Arrays.binarySearch(acceptValues, toAccept.replaceAll("/.*$", "/*")) > -1
                    || Arrays.binarySearch(acceptValues, "*/*") > -1;
        }

        /**
         * Returns true if the given match header matches the given value.
         * @param matchHeader The match header.
         * @param toMatch The value to be matched.
         * @return True if the given match header matches the given value.
         */
        public static boolean matches(String matchHeader, String toMatch) {
            String[] matchValues = matchHeader.split("\\s*,\\s*");
            Arrays.sort(matchValues);
            return Arrays.binarySearch(matchValues, toMatch) > -1
                    || Arrays.binarySearch(matchValues, "*") > -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Use in Controller:

```
MultipartFileSender.fromPath(pathtofile)
                .with(httprequest)
                .with(httpresponse)
                .serveResource();
```

Comment: I cannot find jat with following class: **lan.dk.podcastserver.utils.MimeTypeUtils**

Comment: Removed that import and changed to have the mimetype fixed to "video/mp4", but the entire project is posted at github: https://github.com/davinkevin/Podcast-Server

Comment: Now it is SO style. question - answer wihout redundant context. I am sure it will be useful for future googlers.

Comment: Is there any way to change the default implementation of the Static resource resolver of spring(older version than 4.2RC1), with a controller that can support http range, for download resume ?

Comment: There is a new task https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13834 - please vote for it...

Comment: This has a bug in the multipart branch. Skipping the stream by the full amount every time won't read the expected bytes unless the stream is marked / reset for each read. The better alternative is (of course) to adjust the offset according to the last read position.

Comment: `if (!range.matches("^bytes=\\d*-\\d*(,\\d*-\\d*)*$")) {` should use `if (!range.matches("^bytes=((\\d+-\\d*|-[1-9]\\d*),\\s*)*(\\d+-\\d*|-[1-9]\\d*)$){` so it can handle ranges like: `0-0,1-,-1` (`0-0` is first byte only, `1-` is 2nd byte through to last byte and `-1` is last byte only). It may (probably should) also return `SC_REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE` if the byte ranges overlap otherwise you will get denial-of-service attacks requesting byte ranges like `0-,0-,0-,0-,0-,0-,0-,0-,0-,0-` when the same byte range is requested multiple times for a large file.

Comment: A simple solution for handling non-static resources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45785915/194900

Comment: @LeandroCarracedo can this be used say we want to upload a video but we want it to upload only 1 minute of the video and not the whole video ?

Comment: @LeandroCarracedo the solution you provided works fine for client which only does range requests. I am facing issues in implementing it for pdf viewer.html. I am able to initiate range request from client side that is the viewer does normal request for first time and based on response headers it cancels the on going request and starts range request. I am able accomplish till here but the client is requesting only 1 range request(1st range) its not requesting for all other ranges. Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 32):

It's 2020 here.

Partial ranges are implemented in Spring by default (I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.4). My controller code looks similar to the one below and it works just fine with range headers.

```
return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new FileSystemResource(file))
```

Notes (See [The Almighty Source Code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/1984cfe9d79e8a34955a393ef9d71a2a3d11a87c/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java#L196-L213) for details):

- Spring requires the response to be set to 200 and internally (if range headers are present on the request) replaces it with 206 Partial Content.
- Spring also requires the response to be a Resource instance **except** InputStreamResource for which it fails. For files FileSystemResource seems to be the best choice.

Comment: This is the best answer today.  No custom code needed.

Comment: my code lloks like URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("nbch_intro.mp4");
return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new FileSystemResource(resource.getFile())); In this case, server returns JSON.. When I add .header("Content-Type", "video/mp4"), i get an exception: No converter for [class org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource] with preset Content-Type 'video/mp4'...

Comment: The 2 notes and link to the almighty source code saved my day.. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid `MimeTypeUtils`, you can use `Files.probeContentType(Path path)`. That will use the default implementation of the system.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Leandro worked perfectly for me. I only changed the InputStream with a RandomAccessFile, it is performing better to access a random point inside a file.

Here is the class MultipartFileSender

```
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MultipartFileSender {

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 20480; // ..bytes = 20KB.
    private static final long DEFAULT_EXPIRE_TIME = 604800000L; // ..ms = 1 week.
    private static final String MULTIPART_BOUNDARY = "MULTIPART_BYTERANGES";

    Path filepath;
    HttpServletRequest request;
    HttpServletResponse response;

    public MultipartFileSender() {
    }

    public static MultipartFileSender fromPath(Path path) {
        return new MultipartFileSender().setFilepath(path);
    }

    public static MultipartFileSender fromFile(File file) {
        return new MultipartFileSender().setFilepath(file.toPath());
    }

    public static MultipartFileSender fromURIString(String uri) {
        return new MultipartFileSender().setFilepath(Paths.get(uri));
    }

    //** internal setter **//
    private MultipartFileSender setFilepath(Path filepath) {
        this.filepath = filepath;
        return this;
    }

    public MultipartFileSender with(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        request = httpRequest;
        return this;
    }

    public MultipartFileSender with(HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
        response = httpResponse;
        return this;
    }

    public void serveResource() throws Exception {
        if (response == null || request == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (!Files.exists(filepath)) {
            logger.error("File doesn't exist at URI : {}", filepath.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return;
        }

        Long length = Files.size(filepath);
        String fileName = filepath.getFileName().toString();
        FileTime lastModifiedObj = Files.getLastModifiedTime(filepath);

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(fileName) || lastModifiedObj == null) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            return;
        }
    long lastModified = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(lastModifiedObj.toInstant(), ZoneId.of(ZoneOffset.systemDefault().getId())).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    String contentType = "video/mp4";

    // Validate request headers for caching ---------------------------------------------------

    // If-None-Match header should contain "*" or ETag. If so, then return 304.
    String ifNoneMatch = request.getHeader("If-None-Match");
    if (ifNoneMatch != null && HttpUtils.matches(ifNoneMatch, fileName)) {
        response.setHeader("ETag", fileName); // Required in 304.
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_MODIFIED);
        return;
    }

    // If-Modified-Since header should be greater than LastModified. If so, then return 304.
    // This header is ignored if any If-None-Match header is specified.
    long ifModifiedSince = request.getDateHeader("If-Modified-Since");
    if (ifNoneMatch == null && ifModifiedSince != -1 && ifModifiedSince + 1000 > lastModified) {
        response.setHeader("ETag", fileName); // Required in 304.
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_MODIFIED);
        return;
    }

    // Validate request headers for resume ----------------------------------------------------

    // If-Match header should contain "*" or ETag. If not, then return 412.
    String ifMatch = request.getHeader("If-Match");
    if (ifMatch != null && !HttpUtils.matches(ifMatch, fileName)) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_PRECONDITION_FAILED);
        return;
    }

    // If-Unmodified-Since header should be greater than LastModified. If not, then return 412.
    long ifUnmodifiedSince = request.getDateHeader("If-Unmodified-Since");
    if (ifUnmodifiedSince != -1 && ifUnmodifiedSince + 1000 <= lastModified) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_PRECONDITION_FAILED);
        return;
    }

    // Validate and process range -------------------------------------------------------------

    // Prepare some variables. The full Range represents the complete file.
    Range full = new Range(0, length - 1, length);
    List<Range> ranges = new ArrayList<>();

    // Validate and process Range and If-Range headers.
    String range = request.getHeader("Range");
    if (range != null) {

        // Range header should match format "bytes=n-n,n-n,n-n...". If not, then return 416.
        if (!range.matches("^bytes=\\d*-\\d*(,\\d*-\\d*)*$")) {
            response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes */" + length); // Required in 416.
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE);
            return;
        }

        String ifRange = request.getHeader("If-Range");
        if (ifRange != null && !ifRange.equals(fileName)) {
            try {
                long ifRangeTime = request.getDateHeader("If-Range"); // Throws IAE if invalid.
                if (ifRangeTime != -1) {
                    ranges.add(full);
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignore) {
                ranges.add(full);
            }
        }

        // If any valid If-Range header, then process each part of byte range.
        if (ranges.isEmpty()) {
            for (String part : range.substring(6).split(",")) {
                // Assuming a file with length of 100, the following examples returns bytes at:
                // 50-80 (50 to 80), 40- (40 to length=100), -20 (length-20=80 to length=100).
                long start = Range.sublong(part, 0, part.indexOf("-"));
                long end = Range.sublong(part, part.indexOf("-") + 1, part.length());

                if (start == -1) {
                    start = length - end;
                    end = length - 1;
                } else if (end == -1 || end > length - 1) {
                    end = length - 1;
                }

                // Check if Range is syntactically valid. If not, then return 416.
                if (start > end) {
                    response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes */" + length); // Required in 416.
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE);
                    return;
                }

                // Add range.                    
                ranges.add(new Range(start, end, length));
            }
        }
    }

    // Prepare and initialize response --------------------------------------------------------

    // Get content type by file name and set content disposition.
    String disposition = "inline";

    // If content type is unknown, then set the default value.
    // For all content types, see: http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp
    // To add new content types, add new mime-mapping entry in web.xml.
    if (contentType == null) {
        contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    } else if (!contentType.startsWith("image")) {
        // Else, expect for images, determine content disposition. If content type is supported by
        // the browser, then set to inline, else attachment which will pop a 'save as' dialogue.
        String accept = request.getHeader("Accept");
        disposition = accept != null && HttpUtils.accepts(accept, contentType) ? "inline" : "attachment";
    }
    logger.debug("Content-Type : {}", contentType);
    // Initialize response.
    response.reset();
    response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", disposition + ";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    logger.debug("Content-Disposition : {}", disposition);
    response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
    response.setHeader("ETag", fileName);
    response.setDateHeader("Last-Modified", lastModified);
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + DEFAULT_EXPIRE_TIME);

    // Send requested file (part(s)) to client ------------------------------------------------

    // Prepare streams.
    try (RandomAccessFile input = new RandomAccessFile(filepath.toFile(), "r");
         OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream()) {

        if (ranges.isEmpty() || ranges.get(0) == full) {
            // Return full file.
            logger.info("Return full file");
            response.setContentType(contentType);
            response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + full.start + "-" + full.end + "/" + full.total);
            response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(full.length));
            Range.copy(input, output, length, full.start, full.length);

        } else if (ranges.size() == 1) {

            // Return single part of file.
            Range r = ranges.get(0);
            logger.info("Return 1 part of file : from ({}) to ({})", r.start, r.end);
            response.setContentType(contentType);
            response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + r.start + "-" + r.end + "/" + r.total);
            response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(r.length));
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT); // 206.
            // Copy single part range.
            Range.copy(input, output, length, r.start, r.length);

        } else {

            // Return multiple parts of file.
            response.setContentType("multipart/byteranges; boundary=" + MULTIPART_BOUNDARY);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT); // 206.

            // Cast back to ServletOutputStream to get the easy println methods.
            ServletOutputStream sos = (ServletOutputStream) output;

            // Copy multi part range.
            for (Range r : ranges) {
                logger.info("Return multi part of file : from ({}) to ({})", r.start, r.end);
                // Add multipart boundary and header fields for every range.
                sos.println();
                sos.println("--" + MULTIPART_BOUNDARY);
                sos.println("Content-Type: " + contentType);
                sos.println("Content-Range: bytes " + r.start + "-" + r.end + "/" + r.total);
                // Copy single part range of multi part range.
                Range.copy(input, output, length, r.start, r.length);
            }

            // End with multipart boundary.
            sos.println();
            sos.println("--" + MULTIPART_BOUNDARY + "--");
        }
    }

}

private static class Range {
    long start;
    long end;
    long length;
    long total;

    /**
     * Construct a byte range.
     * @param start Start of the byte range.
     * @param end End of the byte range.
     * @param total Total length of the byte source.
     */
    public Range(long start, long end, long total) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.length = end - start + 1;
        this.total = total;
    }

    public static long sublong(String value, int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
        String substring = value.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
        return (substring.length() > 0) ? Long.parseLong(substring) : -1;
    }

    private static void copy(RandomAccessFile input, OutputStream output, long inputSize, long start, long length) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read;

        if (inputSize == length) {
            // Write full range.
            while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                output.flush();
            }
        } else {
            input.seek(start);
            long toRead = length;

            while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                if ((toRead -= read) > 0) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    output.flush();
                } else {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, (int) toRead + read);
                    output.flush();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
    private static class HttpUtils {

    /**
     * Returns true if the given accept header accepts the given value.
     * @param acceptHeader The accept header.
     * @param toAccept The value to be accepted.
     * @return True if the given accept header accepts the given value.
     */
        public static boolean accepts(String acceptHeader, String toAccept) {
            String[] acceptValues = acceptHeader.split("\\s*(,|;)\\s*");
            Arrays.sort(acceptValues);

            return Arrays.binarySearch(acceptValues, toAccept) > -1
                || Arrays.binarySearch(acceptValues, toAccept.replaceAll("/.*$", "/*")) > -1
                || Arrays.binarySearch(acceptValues, "*/*") > -1;
        }

    /**
     * Returns true if the given match header matches the given value.
     * @param matchHeader The match header.
     * @param toMatch The value to be matched.
     * @return True if the given match header matches the given value.
     */
        public static boolean matches(String matchHeader, String toMatch) {
            String[] matchValues = matchHeader.split("\\s*,\\s*");
            Arrays.sort(matchValues);
            return Arrays.binarySearch(matchValues, toMatch) > -1
                || Arrays.binarySearch(matchValues, "*") > -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, it may make sense for you to map the request by to the container's default servlet.

I.e., during initialization:

```
ServletContext container = ...

// Map *.mp4 to the default servlet to support range requests

ServletRegistration servletRegistration = container.getServletRegistration("default");
servletRegistration.addMapping("*.mp4");
```

Answer (score 1):

woww, The answer of Leandro so briliant. just create service file follow him 
and use in controller. here my after follow his guidelines

```
@RequestMapping(value = [(SKConstant.URL_PROJECT_API + "/video/{token}")], method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET)
fun getVideo(@PathVariable("token") token: String, response: HttpServletResponse, request: HttpServletRequest): Any?{
         val file = baseService.getByToken(token)
         if(file != null) {
           return MultipartFileSender.fromFile(File(fileService.getUploadFileRealPath(file.uniqueName!!)))
                              .with(request)
                              .with(response)
                              .serveResource()
 }
```

Answer (score -5):

Try this simple code .

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/octet-stream"})
public Response getFile() {
  File file = ... 
  return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
      .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" ) .build();
}
```

Update :

Its wrapping the Spring Jersey jersey.java.net RESTful implementation with spring MVC.

For pure Spring mvc use below code.

```
@RequestMapping("/video") public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getvideo() throws IOException { 
    InputStream in = ... 
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(); 
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM); 
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>IOUtils.toByteArray(in),headers,HttpStatus.CREATED); 
}
```

IOUtils is from apache common jar

Comment: Never convert `InputStream` to `byte[]` in this context. You'll have serious memory issues.

Comment: Won't support http-byte-range