# Spring WebClient download and upload file

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I need to create a process that downloads a file from an API endpoint and uploads it to another API endpoint. The file has a maximum size of 100MB but we will have many processes running in parallel. I'm trying to achieve it with Spring WebClient and without storing the files in memory. The current code is storing the file in memory because the tests with big files are throwing OutOfMemoryError.

Copy method

```
public Mono<SyncStatusType> copy(Strin path1, String path2) {
    
    return this.download(path1)
        .collectList()
        .flatMap(dataBuffers -> 
            this.upload(path2, Mono.just(dataBuffers).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)))
        .map(item -> SyncStatusType.SUCCESSFUL);
}
```

Download method

```
private Flux<DataBuffer> download(String path) {

    return this.getWebClient()
        .get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
            .path(path)
            .build())
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);

}
```

Upload method

```
private Mono<CustomFileDto> upload(String path, Flux<DataBuffer> dataBuffer) {
        
    return this.getWebClient()
        .put()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
            .path(path)
            .build())
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromDataBuffers(dataBuffer))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(CustomFileDto.class)
    }
```

**How can I modify this code so that it doesn't store the file content in memory?**

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63393094/9498804

Answer (score 0):

I have a Spring WebFlux multipart example with uploading/downloading files and storing them in the Mongo GridFS, check the [complete codes on my Github](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/boot-data-mongo-gridfs).

The [testing codes](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/boot-data-mongo-gridfs/src/test/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplicationTests.java) demonstrated interaction from a WebFlux client.