# Fractional streaming response with inputStreamResource

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, amazon-s3

Is it possible to use inputStreamResource to respond in a fractional way to just one request?

The client would make just one request to the endpoint and the server would send the split file until it was sent in full.

```
private val PIECE_SIZE = 2048?



 @RestController
@RequestMapping("/download")
class PdfController {
    private val amazonS3: AmazonS3

    init {
        val credentials = BasicAWSCredentials("mycredential", "myCredential2")

        amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
            .build()
    }

    @GetMapping(value = ["/download/pdf"], produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE])
    fun downloadPdf(): ResponseEntity<Resource> {
        val bucketName = "bucket-name"
        val key = "file.pdf"     
        val s3Object = amazonS3.getObject(GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key))
        val s3InputStream: S3ObjectInputStream = s3Object.objectContent

        val responseHeaders = HttpHeaders()
        responseHeaders.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF
        responseHeaders.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.pdf")

        val inputStreamResource = InputStreamResource(s3InputStream)

        return ResponseEntity(inputStreamResource, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63393094/611819